# Amazon RDS Postgres name or service not known

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I have 2 Amazon EC2 instances.  I am using one for development. I started a new one that I want to get working properly so I can use this cleaner one to make an AMI. I am using Django with a Postgres backend in an RDS instance. The RDS instance is running Postgresql 9.4.4.  The development EC2 instance (which is the one that works) is running Postgresql 9.3.9.  The new instance is running Postgresql 9.3.10.

On the development instance I have no trouble connecting to and using the RDS instance with the command line:

```
psql --host django.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com  --port 5432 --username django_login  --dbname django_db
```

But if I use the same command on the new instance, I get

> psql: could not translate host name "django.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: Name or service not known

Both EC2 instances are in the same security group (launch-wizard-1).  The RDS has a security group with all TCP, all UDP and all IMCP set with launch-wizard-1 as the source.

The development instance is in us-east-1d. The new instance is in us-east-1c. The RDS instance is in us-east-1d.  I suspect that might be the problem but as I understand the RDS documentation it should be fine.  If however, that is the problem, do you know how to change the Availability Zone of an EC2 instance?

I have tried this with the RDS instance set to private and then to public.  It did not make a difference.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the new server have a public IP address?

Comment: I have tried making the RDS public and private with the same result. EC2 instances have both public and private addresses.  I am using ssh to sign into both instances with the private ip.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was as I had suspected.  The instance was in a different subnet.  I made an ami from the instance in us-east-1c, made a new instance in the us-east-1d subnet from the ami.  Now I can connect from the new instance.

BTW - It is not immediately obvious when you create an instance that you should set the subnet to match your other instances.  Look for that option on the instance configuration page.

Comment: Your RDS instance should be accessible from more than just one subnet unless you've done something to lock down the traffic in your other subnets. In a default VPN configuration you would be able to access your RDS instance from all subnets, which is desirable since you want to spread your instances across subnets/availability-zones for redundancy.

Comment: You are right.  That is what I understood from the documentation.  I thought I had checked every configuration for the RDS security group and the EC2 security groups.  I will check again to see if there is a bad setting.  I don't want to make another instance to verify.

Comment: The EC2 instances share launch-wizzard-1. So I don't think that was the problem.  In my desparation, I had even set the RDS sg to accept all traffic.  Here is the sg for the RDS:
All TCP     TCP     0 - 65535   sg-xxxxxxxx (launch-wizard-1)
PostgreSQL  TCP     5432        sg-xxxxxxxx (launch-wizard-1)
All traffic All     All         sg-xxxxxxxx (launch-wizard-1)
All UDP     UDP     0 - 65535   sg-xxxxxxxx (launch-wizard-1)
All ICMP    All     N/A         sg-xxxxxxxx (launch-wizard-1)

Comment: Pretty sure it's not a security group issue. You should look at your subnet ACLs and your routing tables in your VPC.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The RDS is using the default VPC with all four subnets listed.  The ACL is also the default with all four subnets.